# Applying transformation to model without rendering

Tags: c#, xna, raytracing

I'm working on building a ray tracer for a graphics class, part of the setup we are required to do is to scale the model into world space before casting my rays. I've built out the worldMatrix needed. However my first attempt at transforming results in the Bounding box of the model changing but none of the vertices in the VertexBuffer.

This is my first attempt:

```
foreach (ModelBone b in model.Bones)
{
   // apply the model transforms and the worldMatrix transforms to the bone
   b.Transform = model.Root.Transform * worldMatrix;
}
```

I've also tried setting the effect values found in the model meshes like every model drawing tutorial shows, but it is of no avail.

Is there some other way I should be attempting to transform the model?

Answer (score 1):

b.Transform = root * world;   doesn't take into account any data in the bone itself.

possibly you need: b.Transform = root * b * world;

The data in the vertex buffer should remain unchanged throughout the life of the game/app. What happens is that the original (unchanged) vertex data gets transformed in the vertex shader each frame anew by whatever different world matrix you send it through the effect.

Typically, it would go something like this:

```
//class scope fields
Matrix[] modelTransforms;
Matrix worldMatrix;

//in the loadContent method just after loading the model
modelTransforms - new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
model.CopyAbsoluteTransformsTo(modelTransforms);//this line does what your foreach does but will work on multitiered hierarchy systems

//in the Update methos
worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(scale);
boundingBox.Min *= scale;
boundingBox.Max *= scale
//raycast against the boundingBox here

//in the draw call
eff.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix;
```